# Which Darkmoon Faire games are phased?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've noticed that the [Whack-A-Gnoll](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=101612) minigame is phased, meaning that all participants see different phased units (eg. the [gnoll barrels](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=54546)). I assume this is to avoid players stepping on each others toes while attempting to achieve their objectives.

Which other Darkmoon Faire games are phased, if any?

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question as some Darkmoon Faire games are phased. Phasing is different from instancing. For more info: http://www.wowwiki.com/Phasing

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the word I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's the only one. I played each and every game each and every day. I watched the Turtle Toss and saw other players' rings landing on the turtle. The Tonk Tanks game, players can kill each others tanks, and I've seen one of them destroy one of the targets on my screen. He Shoots, He Scores shooting game, you all are shooting at the same target. Cannonball, everyone is sent flying through the air, and I've been right on top of someone, or behind someone, and we both land in the same target.

Comment: Players can shoot each other in the Tonk game? I've never successfully shot a player's tonk, nor has mine ever been shot by (nor taken damage from) a non-NPC.

Comment: The player tanks are purple, and I've personally killed another players' tank before. Edit: Try harder. You'll hit any targets in front of you before you will another player, so it can be difficult, but not impossible.

Comment: This adds a whole new level to the Faire, for me. Finally, a reason to buy more tokens! >:D